# Entity Framework error Keyword not supported: provider \r\nconnection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller, connection-string

I have made `MVC API` using Entity Framework. It worked fine on my PC as localhost on Visual studio 
when I published it and I hosted the api and the database on myasp.net to test it and just replaced this connectionstring :

```
<add name="ENGeekEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.operation.csdl|res://*/Models.operation.ssdl|res://*/Models.operation.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=ENGeek;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

with the site connectionstring:

```
<add name="ENGeekEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.operation.csdl|res://*/Models.operation.ssdl|res://*/Models.operation.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider 
connection string=&quot;Data Source=SQL5025.myASP.NET;Initial Catalog=DB_A0A604_ENGeek;User Id=DB_A0A604_ENGeek_admin;Password=MyPassword;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

When I try to get data it gives me this error:

> "Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Keyword not supported: 'provider \r\nconnection string'"

Any Ideas !!

Comment: Edit your question and add the inner exception

Comment: What should I do to get the inner exception

Comment: Click on View Details -> Innerexception when error or exception occurs

Comment: I Managed to it with another way
It gives : 
Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Keyword not supported: 'provider \r\nconnection string

Answer (score 0):

The reason you were getting this error because of the `&quot;` in your connection string.
Replace `&quot;` with single quotes `'` like below.

```
<add name="ENGeekEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.operation.csdl|res://*/Models.operation.ssdl|res://*/Models.operation.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider 
connection string='Data Source=SQL5025.myASP.NET;Initial Catalog=DB_A0A604_ENGeek;User Id=DB_A0A604_ENGeek_admin;Password=MyPassword;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Is `&quot; ` an issue!!

Comment: If you are passing in the `connection string` to the class object then make sure that it has single quotes and If you are getting the connection from the `.config` file, then it is fine to use the `&quot;` escape sequence.

Comment: @RahulNikate I don't believe there should be any difference, any links to support that.I am curious , i never know that

Comment: <add name="ENGeekEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.operation.csdl|res://*/Models.operation.ssdl|res://*/Models.operation.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider 
connection string='Data Source=SQL5025.myASP.NET;Initial Catalog=DB_A0A604_ENGeek;User Id=DB_A0A604_ENGeek_admin;Password=MyPassword;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: @ShekharPankaj [Here's the reference for it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2008/12/09/explicit-connection-string-for-ef/)

Comment: Is there any thing else to do after hosting on server ?!

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
There were two problems.
The first problem was in serializing IEmunerable ,I repalced it with JavaScriptSerializer.
The second one solved by adding single quotes Like mentioned